# Repeat symbol in the middle of the measure because of my lyrics and a starting rest

Tags: lilypond, repeats, lyrics

I know what my problem is, just can't find how to solve it.

I have this (I hope) minimum example showing exactly what my problem is :

```
\version "2.18.2"
\language "italiano"

\score {
  \new ChoirStaff \relative do' <<

    \new Voice = "test" {
      R1
      \repeat volta 2 { si'4\rest }
          \alternative { { do } { do } }
    }

    \new lyrics = "test"

    \context Lyrics = "test" {
        \lyricsto "test" {
          \repeat volta 2 { te -- }
          \alternative { { st -- ing } { st -- er } }
        }
    }
  >>
}
```

Since my measure at the beginning of the repeat starts with a `rest`, two repeats are created, one for the melody, the other one for the lyrics. How can I delete the one corresponding to the lyrics ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a hidden note in `Voice = "test"` to match the rhythm of the lyrics.

Then create another voice, containing just the rest.

Note, you need to explicitly create a staff for the two voices, otherwise you get two separate staves within the `ChoirStaff`.

I deleted `\new lyrics = "test"` which produces a warning message

```
\version "2.18.2"
\language "italiano"

\score {
  \new ChoirStaff \relative do' <<

    \new Staff <<
      \new Voice = "test" {
        R1
        \repeat volta 2 { \hideNotes si'4 \unHideNotes }
            \alternative { { do } { do } }
      }
      \new Voice {
        s1
        \repeat volta 2 { si4\rest }
            \alternative { { s4 } { s4 } }
      }
    >>

    \context Lyrics = "test" {
        \lyricsto "test" {
          \repeat volta 2 { te -- }
          \alternative { { st -- ing } { st -- er } }
        }
    }
  >>
}
```

[image]